# Ember.js Handlebars BoundHelper Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'split'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, internationalization, handlebars.js

I'm making a handlebars helper to simplify translation for an Ember app. It needs to be able to bind to a count option, because the count will change over time, and the translation needs to be plural or singular based on the count.

For example:

```
{{i18n translation.key countBinding='numberCount'}}
```

will go to the language file and see

```
translation: {
  key: {
    'one': 'widget',
    'other': 'widgets'
  }
}
```

and will return 'widget' or 'widgets' depending on the value of `numberCount`

Here is the code for the helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('i18n', function(property, options) {
  var params = options.hash,
    self = this;

  // Support variable interpolation for the options
  Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
    params[key] = Em.Handlebars.get(self, params[key], options);
  });

  // Coerce number-like strings into numbers
  if (params.count && !isNaN(params.count) && typeof(params.count) == "string") {
    params.count = Number(params.count);
  }

  // I18n is the library that powers the translation
  return I18n.t(property, params);
});
```

If I use `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper` instead of `registerBoundHelper`, it works fine, it just won't bind to the option. But when I try to make it a bound helper (as in the code above), the app will not load and the console gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'split' "

Here are the docs for Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper

Answer (score 0):

Would it be work if we replace

```
var params = options.hash
```

with

```
var params = options.hash.boundOptions
```

And

```
{{i18n translation.key countBinding='numberCount'}}
```

with

```
{{i18n translation.key count=numberCount}}
```

?
It works in my test environment.

Comment: No, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object " when I use `registerHelper` and the same "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined " when I use `registerBoundHelper`

Comment: Hmm. Second replacement (contenBinding->content) would work in new handlebars and ember versions. Try just 1st replacement or check value of numberCount (it should not be undefined/null).

Comment: From what I could tell, the problem was that the Bound Helper automatically treated the argument (`translation.key`) as a variable, and I was giving it a string. The normal helper didn't do this.